# dynamic child elements with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a solution to create an ancestor and child element in jQuery?

`$('#tblSample tr:last').after('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');`

It looks like

```
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
</tr>
```

But how can I produce DYNAMIC `<td></td>` child elements between `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags?

Comment: You mean, alter the contents of your `<td>`s? Just concatenate your variables into the string: `.after('<tr><td>'+text1+'</td><td>'+text2+'</td></tr>')`

Comment: Create the row as DOM element (or jQuery object), keep a reference to it and append as many children as you want to. Then add the row to its container.

Comment: please explain `DYNAMIC child elements`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
$('#tblSample tr:last').append('<td></td>');
```

It will add a `td` element inside last `tr` of `tblSample`